# Restore SVN repository history after moving

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion: Moving Directories with History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108567/subversion-moving-directories-with-history)

I have old `svn` repository where all files located at the root.
Now I create folders trunk, branches and tags and move all files to trunk.
Unfortunately history was lost.

How can i restore history?

Before:

```
/repository/folder1
/repository/folder2
```

After:

```
/repository/trunk/folder1
/repository/trunk/folder2
```

Comment: Exactly how did you move the files?

Comment: Do you mean you copied the files outside of the repository?

Comment: No. I use command svn move from /repository/folder1 to /repository/trunk/folder1 and from /repository/folder2 to /repository/trunk/folder2

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/108567/761095

Comment: I am already move folders but on stackoverflow.com/q/108567/761095 not yet