# Modify SVN folder hierarchy, add new folder without losing revision history

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I have a following directory structure committed in SVN with multiple revisions:

```
Folder_A
    \Sub_Folder_B
        \File1
        \File2
```

I want to modify above sturucture to following structure in SVN:

```
Folder_A
    \Sub_Folder_C
        \Sub_Folder_D
            \Sub_Folder_E
                \File1
                \File2
```

I do not want to loose the SVN revision history of Folder_A, File1 and File2.

Please recommend how can I do that?

Should I do it in working copy or svn repository?

Thanks!

EDIT: As I explained in comment, I am not looking for just renaming a folder. I want to introduce new sub folders while maintaining revision history.

Comment: You can use svn mv SRC DST - see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108567/moving-directories-with-history

Comment: @JStrahl I know move can help rename a folder while maintaining its revision history. But I am looking for introducing new sub folders as well while maintain revision history. I am not sure how Add Folder can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the subfolders with svn add DIR, e.g.,

```
svn add Sub_Folder_C
```

.
Then commit the new folders (you may need to do one at a time). Then use svn mv to move from current folder to subdirectory:

```
svn mv Sub_Folder_B Sub_Folder_C\Sub_Folder_D\Sub_Folder_E
```